# Why does Ruby use nil to name the null object?

Tags: ruby

Googled but did not find an answer.

Is there something special about the name nil?

Is the concept of nil different from the null in other languages?

Comment: Nil means nothing/nonexistent. Ask Matz. It's not different.

Comment: Just a guess: Ruby is very lisp-like and `nil` is a value in lisp. It has been around a very long time in many lisp dialects and also Pascal. In comparison, `null` may be the "newer idea."

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, "nil" is the traditional name for the reified concept of "nothing" in Lisp and Smalltalk†. The word "null" is used as an adjective meaning "empty", as in "the null list," which is nil.

Meanwhile, "null" is traditionally a pointer value in C that signifies the pointer doesn't point to anything valid. It refers to the fact that the pointer is null (in the same sense that Lisp uses the word), but it came to be thought of as a value on its own.

Matz was a fan of both Smalltalk and Lisp, so he went with their terminology. There isn't really an important difference in meaning between the two terms — one is just C-ish.

<sup><sup>†</sup> Actually, "nil" existed in a lot more languages than just those. Even Algol-68, the great granddaddy of C, called it "nil". I'm not sure if C *invented* "null" as the name for the null reference or just popularized it, but I'm pretty sure that all the modern languages using that term got it from C.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Many programming languages have a way to represent the absence of information. Sometimes you'll see `null`, sometimes, `nil`, and in Python we have `None`.

There is no universal difference between `nil` and `null` and `None`. What is interesting is that fact that there are differences in the way different languages use `null` for example: in some languages, it can only be used in a pointer context; sometimes it is a keyword; sometimes it is just an identifier; sometimes it is a primitive; sometimes it is an object.

But there is nothing that says you have to use `nil` to mean this and `null` to mean that.

The choice of the word to mean nothing is up to the language designer.  Matsumoto preferred `nil`; that is all.

FWIW, some languages go one step further and distinguish the concept of nothing from the concept of I don't care.  JavaScript comes to mind here:

```
var supervisor = null;       // I definitely do NOT have a supervisor.

var supervisor = undefined;  // I may or may not have supervisor.  I may or may not
                             // even know if I do.  Or it is not relevant.  Or it is
                             // none of your business.
```

Language designers may or may not decide to use this distinction in their language.  I've never seen anything like this for `null` vs. `nil`, though.

Answer (score 6):

I am an old school programmer. I programmed professionally over thirty years ago. A lot of programming has passed me by.  But I would like to point out a bit of old school that hasn't been mentioned.

There is an ASCII character called null.  It's binary value is 00000000.  It is an actual character.  We used to ask "is the null character really null?".

My suggestion, which is a change of mind for me, is to reserve the word null for the null character and use nil when meaning "nothing".

Historically:  We used sending a bunch of nulls to some place in order to create a pause when sending data.