# Returned types and conditions

Tags: ruby, types

Why to have chosen to return `nil` 
Instead of `null` like in other lang ?

Does it have a special meaning ?

And also why used `elsif` instead of `else if` or `elseif` like the others?

Comment: FWIW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108397/why-does-ruby-use-nil-to-name-the-null-object

Comment: What "other languages" do you mean? Syntax varies hugely among languages and is mostly a result of what the language designer liked best.

Comment: About `nil`, the subject has been (very) well discussed [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44422/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-nil-for-representing-null-nodes)

Answer (score 1):

There's only one answer to this: [Because Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto).

Designing a language means making decisions and quite often these decisions lead to different outcomes than the decisions made in other languages.

`nil` is similar to `null` in other languages but it has a number of interesting properties:

- It's an object of NilClass.
- You can call methods on it: `nil.to_s` is valid code.

`null` and `undefined` are two different concepts in other languages, but Ruby tries to coalesce those together.